# How do I join individual elements into a list of strings in Python

Tags: python, string, list, join

I have a list of lists, say `y = [[2, 4, 6, 7], [9, 0, 8, 12], [1, 11, 10, 5]]`
I want to convert each of the inner lists into a strings separated by '/' and output a list of the individual strings. How can I do this in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [str.**join**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) after [mapping](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) the ints to strings within a [list comprehension](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python):

```
>>> y = [[2, 4, 6, 7], [9, 0, 8, 12], [1, 11, 10, 5]]
>>> formatted_y = ['/'.join(map(str, inner_list)) for inner_list in y]
>>> formatted_y
['2/4/6/7', '9/0/8/12', '1/11/10/5']
```

Or if you prefer you could use a couple of nested list comprehensions:

```
>>> formatted_y = ['/'.join(str(x) for x in inner_list) for inner_list in y]
>>> formatted_y
['2/4/6/7', '9/0/8/12', '1/11/10/5']
```

To go back to the original you can use [str.**split**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) within a list compression:

```
>>> original_y = [list(map(int, inner_str.split('/'))) for inner_str in formatted_y]
>>> original_y
[[2, 4, 6, 7], [9, 0, 8, 12], [1, 11, 10, 5]]
```

Comment: Thank you for this. How do I undo the join() operation? I am using these lists as dictionary keys, but I later would need to undo the join in order to operate on the list.

Comment: @EArwa There you go :)

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

```
y = [[2, 4, 6, 7], [9, 0, 8, 12], [1, 11, 10, 5]]
myNewList = []
for myList in y:
    myMap = map(str,myList)
```

**map**(function, iterable) is used to apply a function ('**str**' in this case) to all elements of a specified iterable ('**myList**').

```
    myString = '/'.join(myMap)
```

**join**(iterable) returns a string which is the concatenation of the strings in iterable. The separator between elements is the string providing this method.

```
    myNewList.append(myString)
```

list.**append**(elem) appends an element to the end of the list.

```
print(myNewList)
```

['2/4/6/7', '9/0/8/12', '1/11/10/5']

Comment: Thank you. How can I undo the join() operation if I need to operate on the list as numbers?